# two mutually singular measures witch both support is whole $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: singular-measures

I have some problem with an exercise(for homework):

> Find two mutually singular measures $u$ and $v$ (Borel finite on $\mathbf{R}$) with $$\mathrm{supp}(u)=\mathrm{supp}(v)=\mathbf{R}.$$

I tried to solve exercises in this way:
$$  u(A)= 1 \ \text{ if }\ |A \cap Q|\geq 1,\  \text{ otherwise }\  0. $$
$$  v(A) =1 \ \text{ if }\   |A \cap I| \geq 1, \ \text{ otherwise }\  0.  $$
It is clear that supp(u) = supp(v) = **R**. But is $u \perp v?? $.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what problem would that be? :)

Comment: You know :) :) in solving problem :) :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r_n:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and $s_n:\mathbb{N}\to\pi+\mathbb{Q}$ be an enumeration of the numbers of the form $\pi+{}$(*a rational*). Let $\delta_a$ be the Dirac measure supported at $x=a$, i.e.

$$\delta_0(A)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }a\notin A\\1&\text{ if }a\in A\end{cases}$$

Define $$\begin{align}\mu&:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\delta_{r_n}\\\nu&:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\delta_{s_n}\end{align}$$

To check they are mutually singular consider the sets $A:=\mathbb{Q}\cup((-\infty,0)\setminus(\pi+\mathbb{Q}))$ and $B:=(\pi+Q)\cup([0,+\infty)\setminus\mathbb{Q})$. We have that $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$, while $\mu(B)=\nu(A)=0$.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\pi+\mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ we see that for every point every one of its neighborhoods will have positive measure in both $\mu$ and $\nu$. Therefore $$\text{supp}(\mu)=\text{supp}(\nu)=\mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Try finding a set $E$ with closure $\mathbb{R}$, for which $E^c$ also has closure $\mathbb{R}$.  Then define one measure on $E$ and the other on $E^c$.  This way they are mutually singular and they will both have support $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank's. I thought on problem in that way(but I couldn't find measure) :)

Comment: Maybe Q and I= R/Q. I have idea in this way: u(A) = if |A intersect Q|>=1 than 1 otherwise 0. v(A) = if |A intersect I|>=1 than 1 otherwise 0. Do you think that is right conclusion??

Comment: That's close to what I was thinking.  I'm not sure what your definition of 'Borel finite' is, but if the measure needs to be finite ($\mu(\mathbb{R}) < \infty$) then you need to make the measure on $I$ decay at infinity.  Similar statements for the measure on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: 'Borel finite'<=> u(E) < \infty for E \in Borel algebra. I don't understand how to make measure decay at infinity. If I make u(A) as previous, measure u(R) =1. Isn't it?? Or??

Comment: Just start with a measure $\mu$ on all reals which is Borel finite (e.g. the gaussian).  When you set $\mu$ to zero on the rational numbers you preserve Borel finiteness.

Comment: To "set a measure to zero on the rational numbers" when the measure is gaussian refers to a concept I cannot fathom. Please explain. (The same remark applies to the answer itself, for example I do not know what "a measure on $\mathbb Q^c$" refers to. But the OP must know, since they accepted this answer immediately?)

Comment: Given your history on the site @Did I get the feeling that you take issue with my answer, rather than fail to understand what I'm getting at.

Comment: Setting a measure $\mu$ to zero on a Borel set $A$ would refer to having a provided measure $\mu$, which is used to generate a measure $\mu'$ by the following two rules: $\mu'(B)$ should preserve the measure $\mu(B)$ for $B \subset A^c$ and set $\mu'(B) = 0$ for $B \subset A$ (assuming, yes, that $B$ is measurable).

Comment: For example, the Lebesgue measure is zero on $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$?

Comment: If you are taking $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu'$ to be the Lebesgue measure `set to zero' outside $[0,1]$, then yes, that's an example.  However, the measure on the rationals doesn't change when you restrict to a smaller interval.